Control Flow Graph and Cyclomatic Complexity for this Python Code
1. def is_prime(n):                        
2.    if n <= 1:                          
3.        return False                    
4.    if n == 2 or n == 3:                
5.        return True                     
6.    if n % 2 == 0 or n % 3 == 0:         
7.        return False                    
8.    i = 5                               
9.    while i * i <= n:                   
10.       if n % i == 0 or n % (i + 2) == 0:
11.           return False                
12.       i += 6                           
13.   return True                         

Calculating the cyclomatic complexity purely by the formula: M = Decision Nodes + 1, one gets cyclomatic complexity as 6.
But, when I draw the control flow graph for the same and use the formula M = E - N + 2, I get the answer as 5. Why is there discrepancy?

P.S.: The nodes represent the line numbers. Nodes followed by an alphabet (4a, 4b, etc.) depict the two logical conditions about logical OR.

I think it is reasonably well explained here McCabe CCI. The thing with CCI is that it tells you how many distinct paths there are through the code (=minimum number of test cases need). The +/-1 error isn't really important what is valuable is knowing how far you can go on the CCI metric and still understand the algorithm completely. It can be a good heuristic for finding bugs in legacy code since anything you see with a CCI > 50 is quite likely to contain undiscovered bugs!

Thank you, @MartinBrown! After further analysis, I realized that for scenarios involving multiple exit points, a different formula applies. Using that specific formula, the computed answer aligns with the flow graph in my analysis and the Cyclomatic Complexity comes out as 5.
Additionally, I appreciate your explanation—it clarified the concept in a more general context. My original question stemmed from an academic perspective, as this topic is part of a course I am currently pursuing at university.

If you understand CCI, test cases and where your own limitations on safe levels of complexity are you can make your own code more reliable. You can also take a very good guess at where problems are likely to lurk in legacy code or projects that you have been sent in to sort out at some late stage as a trouble shooter. Modern static analysis tools are much better than they used to be in the old days. Glad to see CCI is making a bit of a comeback. IME It was invariably obscure rare error cases that went untested until they actually happened in reality and were found wanting (or not).
